# How can I calculate a 28.5 mm hole for a hyperboloid center opening when it's Z=0

Tags: python, animation-nodes, mathematics

How can I calculate a 28.5 mm hole for a hyperboloid center opening when it's Z is equal to 0

The arrows point to where z=0 and the 28.5mm hole should be.  (I know I could scale the object but I need to use the formula to animate other values)

I'm using animation nodes and python to animate it see attached file

[image]

```
import bpy
import math

def parametricfunc(uval_a, uval_b, zaxis_a, zaxis_b, num_x, num_y):
    
    
    # mesh arrays
    verts = []
    faces = []

    # mesh variables
    #num_x = 40
    #num_y = 40
    
    pi = math.pi
    PHI = (1+math.sqrt(5))/2 #1.61803398874989
    phi = (1+math.sqrt(5))/2-1 #0.61803398874989
    rmse_PHI = PHI * math.sqrt(0.5) # 0.707*PHI =1.144
    rmse_phi = phi * math.sqrt(0.5) # 0.707*phi
    golden_angle_rad = pi*(3-math.sqrt(5)) #2.39996322972865
    golden_angle_deg_sm = math.degrees(golden_angle_rad)  # 137.507764050038
    golden_angle_deg_bg = 360-golden_angle_deg_sm #222.492235949962

    #print("type ux=%s" % (type(frame)))
    
    # fill verts array
    for i in range (0, num_x):
        for j in range(0,num_y):
            # nomalize range
            
            u = 8*(i/num_x-1/2)
            v = 2*math.pi*(j/(num_y-1)-1/2)
            
            x = 2*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.cos(v)*(uval_a/12)
            y = 2*math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.sin(v)*(uval_a/12)
            z = uval_b*(u)
            
            vert = (x,y,z)
            verts.append(vert)

    #print("type verts=%s" % (type(vert)))

    # fill faces array
    count = 0
    for i in range (0, num_y *(num_x-1)):
        if count < num_y-1:
            A = i
            B = i+1
            C = (i+num_y)+1
            D = (i+num_y)
            face = (A,B,C,D)
            faces.append(face)
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = 0
            
        
        edges = AN.algorithms.mesh_generation.grid.quadEdges(num_x, num_y)
        polys = AN.algorithms.mesh_generation.grid.quadPolygons(num_x, num_y)
    return x, y, z, verts, A, B, C, D, faces, edges, polys
            
x, y, z, verts, A, B, C, D, faces, edges, polys  = parametricfunc(uval_a, uval_b, zaxis_a, zaxis_b, num_x, num_y)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why you're calculating it like that? Do you want to change the algorithm or to find the good input values?

Comment: In general you need to find the local minimum of your hyperbola function, which correlates to a certain z (or j) in your case. Lots of examples online. Make sure the function actually places a vertex at that position.

Comment: @lemon I needed to use the parametric equation it allows for easier animation values (x,y,z) with animation nodes and python https://mathworld.wolfram.com/One-SheetedHyperboloid.html

Comment: @RickT ok, but `a` and `c` are the key values here. But you use 8, 2 and 12. So why? And what about the input `uval_a`? `a` in Wolfram explaination should be half of 28.5

Comment: @lemon I was testing to see how to do it by just starting with static values but that didn't turn out well.  `uval_a` is just a value that will be animatable using animation nodes.

Comment: ok but if `uval_a` is animated, you won't have a static value of 28.5. Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola ?

Comment: @lemon the 28.5 value is just where the animation will start from.  I haven't read that link only the link I posted https://mathworld.wolfram.com/One-SheetedHyperboloid.html, is their something I should focus on?

Comment: @RickT, yes a simple way can be a simple planar hyperbola then rotate it around z. So `z = (b/a) * sqrt(x**2 - a**2)` with y=0. And here starting `a` is half of 28.5

Comment: Or parametric for this hyperbola part: `x = a * sqrt(1 + u**2)` and `z = c * u`.

Comment: @lemon Thanks! that helped `a` ended up being 14.26

Comment: ok, have added an answer considering the diameter as input. => uval_a / 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to input the radius here:

[image]

You can change your code by:

```
for i in range (0, num_x):
    for j in range(0,num_y):
        # nomalize range
        
        u = 8*(i/num_x-1/2)
        v = 2*math.pi*(j/(num_y-1)-1/2)
        
        x = math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.cos(v)*uval_a/2
        y = math.sqrt(1+u*u)*math.sin(v)*uval_a/2
        z = uval_b*u
        
        vert = (x,y,z)
        verts.append(vert)
```

As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola)

The base equation is:

$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1
$$

Which gives:

$$
y = \pm \frac{b}{a} \sqrt{x^2 - a^2}
$$

When a and b are defined by:

[image]