# Changing the "angle / curvature" of a mesh created using python and parametric equations

Tags: python, animation-nodes, mathematics

Changing the "angle / curvature" of a mesh created using python and parametric equations.

**I can create a Hyperboloid using Python and Blender:**
[image: img1]

**With the Python script formula snippet:**

```
for i in range (0, num_x):
        for j in range(0,num_y):
            # nomalize range
            
            u = 2*math.pi*(i/(num_y-1)-1/2)
            v = 2*math.pi*(j/(num_y-1)-1/2)
            
            x = math.sqrt(1+u**2)*math.cos(v)*uval_a/2
            y = math.sqrt(1+u**2)*math.sin(v)*uval_a/2
            z = uval_b*(u)/(2*math.pi/1)
            # uval_a changes the diameter of center hole
            # uval_b changes the height
            
  
            vert = (x,y,z)
            verts.append(vert)
```

I can create a "**curvature**" in **one part of the mesh** using the **SimpleDeform** **modifier** with the **Twist** option

[image: img2]

[image: img2bb]

My goal is to create a mesh which curves left and curves right **using Python**, similar to the image below.

[image: img3]

**I'm trying to use python because this allows me to quickly test the changes by using animation nodes to change the variables in the equations**

I want to say that the issue is with the **U** and **V** variables but I'm not exactly sure how to change these to cause a curvature.

Ps: I'm using Blender 2.91

Comment: Suggest that `u = 2 * math.pi * (i / (num_y - 1) - 1 / 2)` should both use `num_x` as the divisor, and be in the outer loop.  Re the twist as shown here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/198975/15543 you are making the profile then spinning it around z axis  num_y times from (0 to 2pi)  Instead change the phase based on z, (outer loop) to change the range of revolution of each inner loop iteration  eg (-2p, 0) at min z up to (0, 2pi) at nax z,

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks, I changed `u` and `v` to `2 * math.pi * (i / (num_x - 1) - 1 / 2` and placed them in the outer loop.  But got I confused when you said to change the phase based on z (outer loop).  Should I place the `z` variable in the outer loop?

Comment: Z is a function of u. Sorry for confusion... but yeah change range (phase) of innerloop in outer loop.  Simply adding u to v will have this effect.